# LensFlare Issue in Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm using react three fiber and attempting to use the LensFlare Effect that's on the three js docs but I cannot seem to get it working at all. I'm getting no errors with this:

```
import { extend, useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";
import {
  Lensflare,
  LensflareElement,
} from "three/examples/jsm/objects/Lensflare.js";
import { TextureLoader } from "three/src/loaders/TextureLoader";
import lensflare0 from "../assets/lensflare0.png";
import lensflare3 from "../assets/lensflare3.png";

extend({ Lensflare, LensflareElement });

const Flares = () => {
  const [flare0, flare3] = useLoader(TextureLoader, [lensflare0, lensflare3]);

  return (
    <pointLight
      intensity={3}
      position={[2, 2, 2]}
      color="white"
    >
      <lensflare>
        <lensflareElement texture={flare0} size={60} distance={0.6} />
        <lensflareElement texture={flare3} size={70} distance={0.7} />
        <lensflareElement texture={flare3} size={120} distance={0.9} />
        <lensflareElement texture={flare3} size={70} distance={1} />
      </lensflare>
    </pointLight>
  );
};

export default Flares;
```

anyone might have any idea?

Comment: I have a similar issue, the lensflare is displayed as a grey square. Same thing for you ? Have you found a solution?